# Error in finding elements of one series which are not in another

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I am trying to find elements in a series, s1 that are not there in series, s2.

```
s1 = pd.Series(range(1,6))
s2 = pd.Series(np.array(range(1,6))*2)

pd.Series([item for item in s1 if item not in s2])
```

I get only the element '5' as the output. Whereas, I should get a series of 1,3,5 as the output.

Similarly, for another example

```
s1 = pd.Series(range(2,8))
s2 = pd.Series(np.array(range(1,6))*2)

pd.Series([item for item in s1 if item not in s2])
```

I get only the elements 5,6,7 as outputs. The element 3 isn't received in the output.

Can anyone please guide me on what is happening here?

Comment: `s1[~s1.isin(s2)]`?

Comment: Also `np.setdiff1d`.

Comment: item in s1 check by the index, you need that @QuangHoang said

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @QuangHoang. I get the right answer by applying your suggestions but I wanted to understand why the list comprehension does not work in this case.

Comment: What @ansev said above. `item not in s2` check if `item` is in **the index** of `s2` or not.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks @ansev. Thanks Quang Hoang